# Find and replace specific word in list of filenames in a folder

Tags: vba

I have written a macro that looks for the word "active" rather than "activ" but some of the filenames in my folder may contain the word "activ". I want to write a macro to search for these and rename them as "active" so the rest of my macro works. i know bits and pieces but can't seem to put a decent code together.

```
If FileName = "*activ*" then 

'also the file name is not just "activ" it maybe "activcn". 
'am i doing this right by putting the **?

FileName = replace(FileName, "activ", "active")

Else 

End if
```

and I need to put a loop in so it runs through the list of files and searches all filenames.

Actually I've found a solution:

```
Dim strFile As String
Dim newPath As String

newPath = "S:\test\"

strFile = Dir(newPath & "*.*")

If strFile = "*activ*" Then

  Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If InStr(strFile, "activ") > 0 Then
      Name strFolder & strFile As strFolder & replace(strFile, "activ", "active")
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
  Loop
Else

End If
```

Just need help with:

```
If strFile = "*activ*" Then
```

As I said earlier, the filename contains more than just "activ" e.g. "activcn".

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the logic and variable names in your example are a bit messed up... Here's what I think you mean:

```
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolder As String

strFolder = "S:\test\"

strFile = Dir(newPath & "*activ*.*") ' no need to look at all files using *.*
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Not strFile Like "*active*" Then 'else "active" gets replaced by "activee"
        Name strFolder & strFile _
            As strFolder & Replace(strFile, "activ", "active")
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, it was almost identical to yours, and you had posted yours first!